# how to stop Procedural clouds wobbling when animated

Tags: animation, procedural

total newbie question here. made procedural clouds (eevee) for a camera fly-through animation following cgmatter's [tutorial](https://youtu.be/GhMQN4vVMIU).

when animated their surface is wobbling like ocean waves.

can anyone point me towards how to make the cloud surface steady?

[image]

Comment: if you provide your blend file we can check it out...

Comment: unfortunately am so new a newbie that am unable to get the file to be smaller than 51mb ... even after deleting objects down to the bare minimum etc ... sorry, don't want to waste anyone's time, just can't figure it out atm. will update once have learned more and actually know what i'm doing

Comment: you can also share via dropbox or google drive...or whatever...

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/16YN0_5h5iO6mdYEGTGgtdyPtHL6wWo-W/view?usp=sharing]
this is the reduced blend file. appreciate the assistance

Comment: i download your "reduced" file and let the animation play...and see...nearly nothing. Did you test your reduced file?

Comment: yeah, it should have 1 cloud & a camera flying past it ... was showing ok here ...  here another version with more objects ...: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ODOEzZKtVvH0hL85PPL33XDN0bspTIQ/view?usp=sharing

(maybe was a bit too reduced ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have had some experiences where the `NOISE` is automatically animated. A new random seed generated every frame (if not update). When `Cloud` is available I've used that. Otherwise experiment with some others like `Magic`, `Voronoi`, or `Musgrave`.

Comment: thx, tried replacing noise texture node with said options. musgrave looks nice, but still flickering. the texture clearly moves from frame to frame.

it's not urgent for this animation (was able to use image planes for now), but would still like to find out for future uses.